# Allowing popups in chrome for selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, popup

The website i am trying to navigate to using selenium needs popups enabled in order to log in. however selenium starts chrome with popups disabled. Now I am pretty new to coding, but I found a few people that tell to add the following:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But since im still kind of a noob I don't understand this completely. first of I get an error about syntax in the first line. secondly I can already predict that new chromeOptions(); will raise the error that it's not defined... How do I do this. I just want popups enabled (manual enabling is no solution)

After messing around trying to get it to work I now added:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

And changed the code to:

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
```

Good thing is the program runs. bad thing is that pop ups are still blocked...

Comment: I tested my code with opt.add_argument("start-maximized") instead of ("disable-popup-blocking") and that works! so why doesn't the popup blocking one work? please help. im stuck on this...

Comment: To be extra clear, this is the problem: [**link**](http://imgur.com/V5cRMs2)

Comment: Can you consider summing up your exact business case, your objective and your testing steps? ChromeDriver 2.30 by default opens Chrome with `--disable-popup-blocking`. Do consider sharing the URL incase its public where you are facing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making a custom chrome profile that allows popups and loading this in.

Comment: Can you consider showing us a bit of your work please? Thanks